# Why do all numbers except 0 pass an if statement in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

This is something that I've always wondered. According to MDN, in JavaScript "The if statement executes a statement if a specified condition is true". So then why does this pass the statement?

```
var a = 7;
if( a ) {
    alert('true');
} else {
    alert('false');
}
```

The variable is neither true nor false, so why does it alert "true" instead of just skipping the entire if statement?

Comment: because it is so defined.

Comment: only the following return false.   false, 0, "", null, undefined, NaN

Comment: [Read this documentation for expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Javascript following values are always falsy:

```
false
0 (zero)
"" (empty string)
null
undefined
NaN (a special Number value meaning Not-a-Number!)
```

All other values are truthy, including "0" (zero in quotes), "false" (false in quotes), empty functions, empty arrays, and empty objects.

If you want to compare with *true* without type conversion try `a === true`.

Comment: Ahh I didn't know that "falsy" was a thing. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

"is true" means "an expression that evaluates to a true value" not "is exactly equal to the boolean object `true`".

The formal language can be found [in the specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.5).

> Let exprRef be the result of evaluating Expression. 
>  If
>   ToBoolean(GetValue(exprRef)) is true, then 
>  Return the result of
>   evaluating the first Statement. 
>  Else, 
>  Return the result of
>   evaluating the second Statement.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript `if(var)` evaluates not just for boolean, but also for defined/initialized or non defined variables.

For example, if a var is `undefined` or `null` in that case `if` evaluates them to `false`

Answer (score 0):

As stated by other before, it's performing a boolean test on the variable.
Boolean values are binary; that's to say, the only possible values are 0 and 1, where true = 1, and false = 0.

The value you hard-coded into the if-statement is 7 = 0111, and all it takes is one of those numbers being a '1' to make it pass the test.

It work the same way with letters, except the if statement will convert letters from ASCII to binary: "A" = 0100 0001 (registered as 65 in ASCII. http://www.asciitable.com/) On the other hand, no input will return a false statement.

Answer (score -2):

In a computer, everything is a number. Boolean too, and usually are just one bit: 0 or 1.

But computer use more than one bit to store data, so Boolean are more than 0 or 1, but also 255, 42, or 25, while still having to pass a simple test.

So by convention, 0 is false, and any other value is true.